# Возможно ли изменить внешний вид PUSH уведомлений от стороннего приложения Android?

Tags: android, push-уведомления

Есть стороннее приложение, допустим будильник от которого приходят push уведомления. Задача добавить новую функцию  в само уведомление, которое приходит. Возможно ли это и если да то как?

Answer (score 0):

Стандартными средствами сделать это невозможно.

Нестандартные средства потребуют от вас декомпиляции приложения, переписывания его кода и пересборки. Это очень нетривиальная задача. И зачастую незаконная.